# How to import js file to React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, import

I have Home.js React component located in `./components/Home.js` and ratingStars.js file located in `./js/ratingStars.js`.

And I want to use script from ratingStars.js in my Home component, but using `<script src="js/ratingStars.js"></script>` doesn't work.
How to import js file to React component?

Here is `ratingStars.js` :

```
"use strict"

const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');

if(ratings.length > 0){
    initRatings();
}

//main foo
function initRatings(){
    let ratingActive, ratingValue;
    for (let index = 0; index < ratings.length; index++) {
        const rating = ratings[index];
        initRating(rating);
    }
    //foo for accurance rating
    function initRating(rating){
        initRatingVars(rating);

        setRatingActiveWidth();

        if (rating.classList.contains('rating_set')){
            setRating(rating);
        }
    }
    //init vars
    function initRatingVars(rating) {
        ratingActive = rating.querySelector('.rating_active');
        ratingValue = rating.querySelector('.rating_value');
    }

    //change rating width
    function setRatingActiveWidth(index = ratingValue.innerHTML) {
        const ratingActiveWidth = index / 0.05;
        ratingActive.style.width = `${ratingActiveWidth}%`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import statement and call upon the components in them in this way.
`import <Name of what you want to import> from '<Relative Path>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can import React components like this

```js
import Home  from './components/Home';
```

```js
import ratingStars  from './components/ratingStars';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your js file - `ratingStars.js` looks so:

```
export const ratingStars = () => {...};
```

then you should import it in your React component (`Home.js`) so:

```
import {ratingStarts} from '../js/raintgStars'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `<script src="./js/ratingStars.js"></script>`

or usually in React , we can import js files as following,

```
import ratingStars from './js/ratingStars.js'
```

Comment: So, how can I now use this imported ratingStars in my Home.js?This import is just shadowed in VS Code.

Comment: it will shadowed at the case of when you are not using that 'ratingStars' at your code, start using it , it'll become colored.